# parameter less constructor error

Tags: c#, events, interface, .net-remoting

I'm trying to make my client subscribe to events that happen on my server.

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public delegate void RemoteEventHandler(object sender, ClientEventArgs args);


[Serializable]
public class ClientEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClientEventArgs()
    { }

    public ClientEventArgs(Client _client)
    {
        MyClient = _client;
    }
    public Client MyClient { get; set; }
}

public interface IMonitor
{
    event RemoteEventHandler RemoteEvent;
}
```

My Server Class looks like this:

```
public class ConnectionManager : MarshalByRefObject, IMonitor
{
    public event RemoteEventHandler RemoteEvent;

    // call the below code when th event should fire.
     if (RemoteEvent != null)
            RemoteEvent(this, new ClientEventArgs(e.MyClient));
}
```

Then To set my channels up on the server I do this:

```
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
provider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["port"] = 5001;
TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(props, null, provider);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
typeof(ConnectionManager),
ConnectionManager",
WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

And On the client to set the channels up and subscribe to the event:

```
TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        _monitorObject = (IMonitor)Activator.GetObject(
            typeof(IMonitor),
            "tcp://localhost:5001/ConnectionManager");

_monitorObject.RemoteEvent += _monitorObject_RemoteEvent;
```

Can anyone explain where this is going wrong please?

Exception:

> > System.MissingMethodException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233069   Message=No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
> >     Source=mscorlib

Comment: Does the exception have an inner exception?

Comment: It's failing to load the main assembly or one of its dependencies?

Comment: Then you probably are missing a referenced assembly. Did you only copy the exe?

Comment: After fixing the reference, im getting a no parameter less constructor error?

Comment: You provided a nice stack trace, but not the actual exception...

Comment: @BenVoigt The stack trace has been replaced by the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question: when using `Serializable` you need a constructor without parameters. So this one would definitely fail:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClientEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClientEventArgs(Client _client)
    {
        MyClient = _client;
    }
    public Client MyClient { get; set; }
}
```

You need to add a parameterless constructor:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClientEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClientEventArgs()
    { }

    public ClientEventArgs(Client _client)
    {
        MyClient = _client;
    }
    public Client MyClient { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, after rebuilding its still throwing the same error though.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other places with this problem? Maybe the Exception will tell the failing class?

Comment: The only reference to [Serializable] is in the class from above. Thanks for your patience !

Comment: And what about your `Client` class. It is referenced in the `EventArgs`.

Comment: I've changed that object to type string, do I need to add anything else if ive done that?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. Give it a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50890/discussion-between-lewis-and-patrick-hofman)

Answer (score 0):

My money is on your `ConnectionManager` class not having a default / parameterless constructor. The remoting infrastructure needs to be able to create an instance of it on the server end.

Comment: Thanks for this, it compiles, the event never fires but at least it compiles!